# Django Streaming CSV Download with Nginx/uWSGI

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I am trying to implement CSV Streaming Download from Django Admin. The requirement is to export the listing queryset (about 5L records) and to prevent timeout, I am trying to implement download using HttpStreamingResponse like mentioned in the below link.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/outputting-csv/#streaming-large-csv-files

Instead of fixed rows, I have a queryset with iterator(). All works fine with runserver and as soon as I click the export button the file starts downloading with unknown size and all records are exported.

But on production with uWSGI and Nginx, the file streams only for the duration of time = harakiri value (60s) as set in uwsgi config and consists of limited records captured during that time frame.

Is it possible that uwsgi worker is not killed as part of harakiri settings for a streaming response or have dynamic harakiri setting for different requests?

My Django version is 1.8, uWSGI version is 2.0.12 and Nginx version is 1.4.6

**My uWSGI config (uwsgi.ini) is as under:**

```
[uwsgi]
uid=someuser
gid=someuser
chdir=/home/gor/somedir
home=/home/gor/virtualenvs/somevirtualenv
wsgi-file=%(chdir)/wsgi.py
module=wsgi:application
socket=/tmp/somesock.sock
pidfile=/tmp/someproject.pid
logto=/var/log/uwsgi/someproject.log
vacuum=True
master=True
max-requests=5000
workers=1
chmod-socket=666
harakiri=60
```

**My Nginx config is as under**

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///tmp/someproject.sock; # for a file socket
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      80;
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /home/gor/someproject/uploads;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
        expires 7d;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/gor/someproject/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
        expires 7d;
    }

    location /favicon.ico {
        alias /home/gor/someproject/static/images/favicon.ico; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_read_timeout   60s;
        uwsgi_send_timeout   60s;
    }
}
```